# How to redirect cas login success page to a customize url

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, okta

everyone

I am using CAS and okta to do the SSO , I found a issue that when I input 2nd times SSO url it will show the CAS login page ,

the case is :

sso url in the same browser : https://CBX-PF217JHT-E490.cbxsoftware.com/cas/clientredirect?client_name=ldlint2&service=https://CBX-PF217JHT-E490.cbxsoftware.com/main/j_spring_cas_security_check

1. open a browser tab and input the sso url, it will sso login into my app server
2. open another browser tab and input the sso url again , it will show me that the CAS login successful

anyone know why this happen and is that possible to redirect to a customize url after show such page ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

2021-10-12 11:47:46,137 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.web.flow.DelegatedClientAuthenticationAction] -

issue is in the
org.apereo.cas.web.flow.DelegatedClientAuthenticationAction#doExecute

if already has the sso session , then will not go to the service again